# ErrorException Undefined variable: username LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Just to preface this, I have gone through most of the answers that are aligned to my question, pretty much I have an undefined variable for the user.

I want to log in the user with the session and display the user's name after logging in on the dashboard .following is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    function login1(Request $request){
      $username = $request->input('username');
      $password = $request->input('password');


      $data = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])->get();
      if(count($data)>0){
       $request->session()->put('username',$data);
        return redirect('dashboard');
      }
else{
    
        echo "error";
    
        $notification = array(
                'message' => 'User Does not Exists!',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );
            return back()->with($notification);
      
      
      
}
}}
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.theme')
@section('content')
<style type="text/css">
    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    }
    label{
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .disabled{
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    select.form-control{
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table{
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .wellcometext{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 250px;
        color: black;
    }
    .slogon {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }
    .wellcometext:hover{
  transition: transform .5s;
    }
    .modal-backdrop {
   background-color: black;}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="wellcometext"><b>Welcome To The Hospital Information System.</b></h4>
    <h6 class="slogon">Future Is Integration.</h6><br>
    <h2 class="wellcometext"><B>{{session('username')}}</b><h2>
</div>

@endsection
```

web route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\login;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});
//Route::view('login','login');
Route::view('dashboard','dashboard');
//Route::view('logout','logout');


Route::get('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/cancelorder', function () {
    return view('cancelorder');
});




Route::post('add',[login::class, 'add']);

Route::get('login1','App\Http\Controllers\MainController@login1');


Route::get('/logout',function(){
    if (session()->has('login1'))
    {
        session ()->pull('login1',null);
    }
    return redirect ('login');
});


Route::get('/login',function(){
    if (session()->has('login1')){
        return redirect ('dashboard');
    }
    return redirect ('login');
});
```

Comment: Laravel has perfectly good user authentication and session management. Why re-invent it?

Comment: Where is your Dashboard controller code and view?

Comment: @snapey check now ,i have updated the code

Comment: @Snapey this is how my data is being displayed on the dashboard:this is how my data is being displayed on the dashboard: [{"id":7,"username":"MISSION","password":"PLC","name":"PACSLINK CORPORATION","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}] instead of just displaying username

Comment: Try calling it `dashboard.blade.php` not `dashboard.php.blade`

Comment: And spend some time looking at the documentation / watching tutorials.  You put the whole user model in session as `username` so consequently, thats what you get back

Comment: @Snapey corrected but what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in controller

```
$data = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])->get();

if(count($data)>0){
      .....
      .....
      $request->session()->put('username',$data);
      ......
}

// You will get the user's collection
```

To

```
$data = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])->first();

if($data){
      .....
      .....
      $request->session()->put('user',$data);
      ......
}

// You will get a user object
```

Change in blade file

```
{{session('username')}}
```

To

```
{{session('user')->username}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code corrected. But I recommend you use Laravel's guards and not invent your own authentication methods.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    function login1(Request $request){
      $username = $request->input('username');
      $password = $request->input('password');


      $user = DB::table('users')
         ->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])
         ->first();
      if($user){
       $request->session()->put('user',$user);
        return redirect('dashboard');
      }
else{
    
        echo "error";
    
        $notification = array(
                'message' => 'User Does not Exists!',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );
            return back()->with($notification);
      
      
      
}
}}
```

then in the view

```
<h2 class="wellcometext"><b>{{session('user.name')}}</b><h2>
```

BUT NEVER EVER, NO MATTER WHAT EXCUSE, USE PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS

Answer (score 0):

To show a page and pass variables to it, this is one way to do it:

```php
$data = [1,2,3,4];
$username = 'my_name';

return view('dashboard', compact('data', 'username'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Assuming your user model has been set correctly ;

```
    function login1(Request $request){

      $user = User::where('username',$request->username)->where('password', $request->password);
      
if ($user->exists()) {
            $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->where('password', $request->password)->first();
            Auth::login($user, true); 
            return redirect('dashboard');   
} else {
 return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Incorrect username or password']);
}

}
```

Comment: =larry this is how my data is being displayed on the dashboard: [{"id":7,"username":"MISSION","password":"PLC","name":"PACSLINK CORPORATION","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}] instead of just displaying username and name

Comment: this is my updated code:

Comment: Sorry never noticed blade file. My bad. My advice is you should use laravel's authentication methods, it's more secure and helps you write clean code!